# How do you position your hand to press Command (cmd) + Option (alt) keys?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

Combination <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>some key</kbd> is pretty common in OS X. For example "cut": <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

I'm struggling to press it with one hand. It's hard. Things goes insane if combination also includes <kbd>Shift</kbd> ("Save for Web" in Photoshop - <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

It is easier to press "equivalent" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> on Windows which placed like Ctrl+Command on Mac.

First of all I was trying to avoid <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd> in any sofware I used. But it looks like, it's the "OS X way" and there always be the software containing shortcuts with this combination.

How do live with this? How to make it less painful?

Comment: You asked "_How to make it less painful?_"; Use both hands! ;)

Comment: I use the right side keys a lot, rather than the left [needs the full extended keyboard to have that configuration], Cmd/opt with my thumb, then any finger to reach the letter. I can manage to get Cmd/opt just with my little finger, but not as reliably, then thumb for the long stretch. For the big cmd/shift/opt.. I give up trying to be clever & just use 2 hands ;) Though I can reach cmd/opt/shift/s with only left hand T;cmd, ring;opt, pinky;shift,1st or 2nd;s

Answer (score 2):

I am also suffering the same issue. I think logically and ergonomically these Apple keys really suck.

What I do is that I have to use my both hands. I leave my right hand from mouse and Press cmd key with my right hand and other combination keys from the left hand

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set Option key to Caps lock (nobody really use it) in System preferences. Caps lock placed more useful.

But often people rebind Control to Caps lock, so you have to decide which one is more important to you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread. But I find sticky keys quite useful if you find shortcut with three keys hurting for hand.

Best.

Comment: The reason is simple. with sticky keys enable, you don't have to type three keyboard commands at the same time.